# Magento Save Order function where it is?

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I'm checking since hours into magento files.
Now I'm in checkout onepage `/checkout/onepage/reviews/info.phtml`, the order is saved with this call to Ajax,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
//]]>
</script>
```

I'm new to this syntax, there is no saveOrder file in onepage template folder, I need to hack the saveOrder action to change the redirect from succes page to a payment gateway and come back. 
Where this method is? I really don't understand this call to ajax like a new object instance.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `checkout/onepage/saveOrder` is a route which corresponds to `module/controller/action`. So that would map to:

`INSTALL_PATH/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

and the method you are looking for would be `saveOrder`.

That said you SHOULD NOT EVER go hacking core files. You can an observer or a class rewrite to override the functionality.

- Observers: http://www.solvingmagento.com/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/
- Onepage Checkout walk through: http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-onepage-checkout-part-2-model-views-controller/

Comment: Thanks, no intention to edit core files, just want to understant it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you want to hack saveorder function better to create one observer with

sales_order_save_after
or
sales_order_invoice_save_before

event. its not good directly write in magento core files.